# The same code has different results in different sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, counting, countif

I have a sheet where I keep track of everyone's tasks. It involves counting how many times a time stamp appears in a time period. I use the same code but sometimes the result is different.

[image: 1]

As you can see, It got the 15:00:00 right, but 15:30:00 is not working and get counted as 15:00:00. the same happens to 20:00:00.
The code I use is quite simple :COUNTIFS(filtered range,">=" lower time stamp, same filtered range, "<" higher time stamp)
EX=countifs(B$57:B$68,">="&$A53,B$57:B$68,"<"&$A54)

P/s: after making a sample sheet to post here, it works again, SO I think it may have something to do with a large amount of calculation in the original file. I dont know what is the problem.
P/s: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RW1QafjcaWNxBMHY6YYQr4TVL3I1zMvHd9W7prHYo04/edit#gid=1941403754
here is my sheet with static data instead of a dynamic one. you can see the different between sheet DP v5 and DP v7 since I use the same data for the 2. Please check the number in green.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

optimization...

instead of **418** formulae you use in `B36:W54` use this one formula in `B35`:

```
=INDEX(REDUCE(IFERROR(B2:W2/0), A36:A54, LAMBDA(y, z, {y; BYCOL(B2:W2, 
 LAMBDA(x, COUNTIFS(AF6:AF, "="&x, AG6:AG, "<>"&AD2, 
 AE6:AE,">="&z, AE6:AE, "<"&OFFSET(z, 1, ))))})))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will analyze it and use it to improve other parts like Tutor, CT and KG. However, the problem remains the same, even when I put all other parts to 0 to reduce all the calculations. I can't understand why it works in v5 but not in v7. Anyway thanks again. I'm newbie so your optimization is eye-opening for me.